# .NET Rest Client Frameworks

Tags: .net, http, rest

I'm looking for the best .NET C# framework for building a REST Http client. My requirements are as follows:

- Unit testable (mockable)
- Supports multi-part form and file uploads

I have looked at [Hammock](http://hammock.codeplex.com/), but it is lacking in documentation and seems to be troublesome when attempting to mock file uploads.

Any suggestions, please?

Comment: That Hammock link is dead BTW.  I found the new [official Hammock page](https://github.com/danielcrenna/hammock) on Github but the author added a message on 2/19/2012 that he's not updating it anymore.  There are some forks but none that are very active.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have just submitted a patch for the aforementioned problem with mocking file uploads using Hammock and has been accepted into the trunk. See [issue 13](http://hammock.codeplex.com/workitem/13) for more details.

Answer (score 12):

There is also [RestSharp](http://restsharp.org/).  I've inherited it on some projects and haven't fully explored it myself, so I'm afraid I cannot say if it meets your requirements.

The [developer of RestSharp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1786/john-sheehan) is active in the .Net community, so if the published documentation doesn't cover something I would say there is a good chance of getting some assistance.

Comment: I have looked at RestSharp. Does anybody know if there are any examples of mocking RestSharp clients? I see there are a few libraries that the author has put out (for services like Notifo) which have zero test coverage.

Comment: I'm the RestSharp dev. Our file uploads is not tested very well. We also don't do mocking very well, unless you want to build a custom IRestClient or IHttp implementation. If those are your two biggest concerns, I would go with Hammock.

Comment: See my comment above.  The Hammock author is no longer updating the project so RestSharp or Spring.Rest might be the better bet at this date and time.

Comment: RestSharp -> ServiceStack recommendation (Jul '13 post comment, seems to remain valid as of Dec '18 based on other reading): https://stackoverflow.com/a/10118120/8352092

Answer (score 4):

You can also take a look to Spring.Rest client Framework :
http://springframework.net/index.html#spring-rest-1.0.0-released

Comment: Spring.Rest official project page: [http://www.springframework.net/rest/](http://www.springframework.net/rest/)

Answer (score 3):

Also take a look at the Microsoft.Http client in http://wcf.codeplex.com/  It will be included in future versions of the framework.  It is relatively easy to unit test with.

Comment: +1 Now in ASP.NET MVC. See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/henrikn/archive/2012/02/16/httpclient-is-here.aspx for an example from a guy close to the dev of it

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft HTTP Client Libraries is good option to consider.

Nuget URL - https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Net.Http/

Answer (score 0):

Check the Flurl library https://flurl.dev/
Flurl is available on NuGet and is free for commercial use. It runs on a wide variety of platforms, including .NET Framework, .NET Core, Xamarin, and UWP.