# Example for Box-API calls

Tags: .net, rest, box-api

I have been using box-api v1.0 and now see there is a new one and would like to take advantage of it. However I am very new to REST and don't really understand what to do here.

My code for getting folders was this:

```
wcGetFolders.OpenReadAsync(new Uri("https://www.box.net/api/1.0/rest?action=get_account_tree&api_key=" + api_key + "&auth_token=" + auth_token + "&folder_id=" + currentFolder + "&params[]=onelevel&params[]=nozip"));
```

But now with the new API I am unsure on how to format the string.

Previously I was able to put all the parameters inside the uri.

Can I still do that?

The new API help indicates that the request looks like this:

```
https://api.box.com/2.0/folders/FOLDER_ID \
-H "Authorization: BoxAuth api_key=API_KEY&auth_token=AUTH_TOKEN" \
```

I don't know what to do with the backslashes and the quotes, basically I don't know at all how to format the uri and even if all the -h etc parameters actually go into it at all.

Comment: I think i worked it out. -H stands for header i think. I have now added a header to my WebCall

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example requests in the documentation are given for cURL, a command line tool for making HTTP requests, so that is what the example refers to.

The v2 Box API is RESTful which you can read more about [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_State_Transfer#RESTful_web_services) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/343288/what-am-i-not-understanding-about-rest).

In short, the folder id of the folder you're trying to get information about should be inserted in the resource URL where FOLDER_ID appears.

Your code sample indicates that you're developing in .NET, so I'd recommend using one of the REST libraries available for .NET, many of [which are listed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4073564/net-rest-client-frameworks). You may also find it helpful to utilize a REST client such as [Postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm) for playing around with the API.

Answer (score 1):

In simple terms, just ignore the way the examples are written in the BOX documentation. They just needed to display the information in a programming language independent way, in this case they chose the command line syntax.

-H refers to the header information you will be passing in when you make a HTTP request.

Not sure how it would be in .NET, but in PHP using the cURL library, it would be something like this:

```
$crl = curl_init();

curl_setopt($crl, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.box.com/api/2.0/folders/0');
curl_setopt($crl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Authorization: BoxAuth api_key=API_KEY&auth_token=AUTH_TOKEN',));
curl_setopt($crl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($crl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$results = curl_exec($crl);

curl_close($crl);
```